# Develop android application with device ROM customized

Tags: android, performance

Currently I am developing an android application. This application should load when the device boot and it should restrict all the inbuilt & other applications. I have searched in forums as it can be possible by make our ROM customized. But this process can be do manually by ourselves. I want to make this by coding. Or is there any other way to make my application default?

Comment: It's funny how Android attracts all kinds of folks who think they can get devices under complete control. Reminds me of the good old times. A bit scary, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your app to be default - yes, you haven only way to build your own custom android.

Only what you can do on your default android system is to automatically load your app after OS have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You're not stating precisely what you intend to do. The words *restrict* and *default* can mean a lot of things.

Despite what dilix writes, one way you *might* succeed with what you want is if you make your app a launcher. A launcher plays an interesting role in the system.

However, you cannot force anyone to really use it. But that wouldn't be possible either way, right? Unless you talk to device manufacturers.